# Using Azure Ad connector on Logic app to update Custom security attributes

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

I wanted to connect to the Azure AD using logic app and add Custom security attributes with value for each user.

But there is no filed for it.

[image]

Could it be other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking around then I found that I can use the Microsoft Graph. I'm still figuring out how to work with it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).